# no image users' user cards appear in wrong position

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, user-card

When hovering over a user that doesn't have a display pic, like [Alex Walker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2902555/alex-walker) and [Matthew Haugen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1270504/matthew-haugen) it puts the user's display card in the top left corner of your browser. This happens on /review page as well as when hovering over Matthew's user box in his [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959950/the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process/27960067#27960067).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Exchange does not support the removal of elements via third-party tools (you have something blocking Facebook photos). The popups work fine when you allow the images to load.